# How to pass 2 parameters by using .on()?

Tags: jquery, html, getattribute, dom-node

I'm trying to pass 2 parameters to ajax but i'm not sure how to do it. It works passing the `id` but not the `anotherId`. I already look into [.on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but does not really helped me.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success edit_modal" id="123" anotherId="111">Click</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_modal', function() {
            var id1 = this.id;
            var id2 = this.anotherId;
            console.log(id1); //this returns "123" in console
            console.log(id2); //this returns undefined...why?

            $.ajax({
                    ...
                    data: { "id1":id1, "id2":id2 }
                    ...
            });    
});
```

Comment: Try `this.getAttribute("anotherId")`

Comment: try `$( "[attribute='value']" ).on('click',function() { ...})` - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Use data attributes

Comment: What is to see there @slon? jQuery attr uses getAttribute anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these two:

```
var id1 = this.id;
var id2 = this.anotherId;
```

to:

```
var id1 = $(this).attr("id");
var id2 = $(this).attr("anotherId");
```

Comment: there's no need to change `this.id;` that's vanilla javascript syntax and works without the jQuery wrapper

Comment: @Liam I agree, I just made it to be the same